# How do I fork a VS 2010 VB Solution

Tags: vb.net, version-control

I've written a bare-bones ap in Visual Studio 2010, Express version. It does what I need and several others are using it successfully. I'd like to add features to it, but I don't want to foreclose the ability to make corrections to the present version.

How do I make a fork in the application for this purpose? Google has been no help in this case, and I've tried several incarnations of copy and change names etc etc.

Comment: What do you mean a fork? Can't you copy the solution folder?

Comment: Are you using some sort of source control system? VSS? SVN?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have a Source Code Revision Control System in place (Subversion, TFS, Git  etc.), and then create a branch. That way all names stay the same.

One technique is to create a branch (from the trunk, or a previous branch from trunk) for each different production version you want to support. That way, merging chnages up/down between versions and current development is (usually) relatively straightforward.

Even if you are not using Subversion, the ['Red Bean' book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) is a great place to learn about branching strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010, Express edition doesn't integrate directly with source control systems. This is one of the product limitations (i.e. what makes it  the 'express' license).

I would recommend either:
1. using a product like SVN or Mercurial, which you use outside the Visual Studio IDE
2. depending on the complexity of the changes, you may want to look at conditional compilation. It's kind of like a poor man's code branch.